# I think that there's something wrong with my search method otherwise it should work

Tags: c#, list, search

I am trying to search a list and then extract some objects of it put them into another list and write the list to a file.

I think that my code is right but when I execute it I get a NullReference exception. If someone could check my code would I would be really grateful.

Here's my code for the Search method that I use

```
public void Search( string day)
{
    foreach (Classes c in studentClasses)
    {
        if (c.Day == day)
        {
            studentClassesByDay.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the code which adds the new list to a file

```
private void btnDay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectDayForm selectDay = new SelectDayForm();
        if (selectDay.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            l.Search(selectDay.theDay);
            trg.GenerateSortedListReport(l.studentClassesByDay, AppData.byDay);
            MessageBox.Show("A list of sorted student classes written to file " + AppData.byDay+ ".");
           // txtDay.Text =selectDay.theDay;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this with the supplied information. Do you have anything else? Error details?

Comment: Are you sure your: `studentClasses`,`studentClassesByDay`,`l`,`trg` variables have all been instantiated? Have you run it with the debugger attached to see which line the NRE is happening on?

Comment: Well theDay is a string which is working when I pass it. I have already checked that by displaying theDay on a listbox. That's why I thought that my Search method is wrong. Maybe it doesn't add the objects into the new List because when I tried to display it there was nothing in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown on which line the exception occurs (which would be handy) but you also haven't shown where `studentClassesByDay` has been instantiated.

That would be the *first* thing I would check.

The only possibilities in the code you've shown are:

- `l` is null;
- `trg` is null;
- `l.studentClassesByDay` is null; or
- `AppData` is null (though that's probably not so - it looks like a class).

Simply put some debug statements (or breakpoints in your debugger) before each attempted dereference and check the values.

Based on your comment that the errant line is:

```
studentClassesByDay.Add(c);
```

it's almost guaranteed (as suspected) that you havent actually instantiated this variable. I'd look into that.

Comment: The line is studentClassesByDay.Add(c);